# Change ID string in vcf file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a VCF file with SNP IDs like this:

```
AX-14233402__rs35404821
AX-37499887__rs74704183
AX-36783275__rs11997571
```

I would like to change the SNP IDs to have only the IDs without the `AX-...` term:

```
rs35404821 
rs74704183 
rs74704183
```

Is there any solution for this? I tried with a gsub command, but nothing changed:

```
awk '{gsub(/AX*_rs/,"rs"); print}' datafile.vcf > datafile_ID.vcf
```

Comment: You're confusing `*`s meaning as a regexp metachar (repetition of preceding RE segment) vs as a globbing metachar (any string).

Comment: A simple substitution like this is the job sed exists to do and you could even do this specific thing with `cut` - do you NEED to use awk for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following solution. What this code does is: Setting `__` as a field separator for all the lines, then checking condition if line starts from `AX-` then printing 2nd field of that line.

```
awk -F'__' '/^AX-/{print $2}' Input_file
```

***OR*** in case you want to simply print values after `__` without checking if line starts from `AX-` or not then try following.

```
awk -F'__' '{print $2}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, `*` is used as a quantifier, not as *any text* pattern.

You can use `.*` to match any text between `AX` and rightmost `_rs` (since it is the only `_rs` in your contents, it is fine to use):

```sh
awk '{gsub(/AX.*_rs/,"rs")}1' datafile.vcf > datafile_ID.vcf
```

Note `print` is replaced with `1`, that causes the default `print` action.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/NKGuad):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='AX-14233402__rs35404821
AX-37499887__rs74704183
AX-36783275__rs11997571'
awk '{gsub(/AX.*_rs/,"rs")}1' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
rs35404821
rs74704183
rs11997571
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cut -d_ -f3 file
rs35404821
rs74704183
rs11997571
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to contain more truly representative sample input/output including cases that doesn't work for.

Answer (score 1):

If number of digits after `AX-` is fixed, then use `substr` to get 14th and following element. Let `file.txt` content be

```
AX-14233402__rs35404821
AX-37499887__rs74704183
AX-36783275__rs11997571
```

then

```
awk '{print substr($0,14)}' file.txt
```

output

```
rs35404821
rs74704183
rs11997571
```

Explanation: I get substring of line from 14th character to end using using [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function and `print` it.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: It works, but it is a very broad match though :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `sed`, a simple substitution with `awk`:

```
awk 'sub(/^.*__/,"")' file
rs35404821
rs74704183
rs11997571
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot before the asterix so `AX*` will match an `A` char and zero or more times an `X` char.

Using `gnu awk` you could also get a precise match for the SNP ID's and use/print a capture group for the `rs` part followed by digits only:

```
awk 'match($0, /AX-[0-9]+__(rs[0-9]+)/, a) {print a[1]}' datafile.vcf > datafile_ID.vcf
```

Or using sub, as there seems to be a single replacement only. You don't have to use print because sub returns the number of substitutions (0 or 1)

```
awk 'sub(/^AX-[0-9]+__rs/,"rs")' datafile.vcf > datafile_ID.vcf
```

Content in file "datafile_ID.vcf":

```
rs35404821
rs74704183
rs11997571
```